# Xpages how to stop javascript library Outline updates on every click, scroll or change?

Tags: javascript, xpages

As per the subject i have disabled all the settings in the domino editor under the javascript editor section. If it was on a change I can live with but for every single click or scroll I do it will recompile the entire script making it very unusable and slow to code with. Does anyone have any suggestions on how i could solve this? Maybe an eclipse setting i can change that's in the background?

I am currently running IBM Domino Designer 9.0.1 Social Edition

Best regards,

Kolhammer

Comment: I'm assuming that 'Outline' is a JavaScript library that you want to use in your XPage application. How did you add it to your XPage? Using the 'resources' section? That might be causing the issue. I normally use a theme to include 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @MarkLeusink I think he refers to Outline view

Comment: Ah that one... Then sorry: I don't know anything to stop that behaviour. Best option would be to switch to the 'Reference' tab.